# Selecting keys of a TreeMap by their index

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Imagine you have the following TreeMap:

```
var dates = new TreeMap[Long, Tuple2[Int, Double]]()
```

I know I can loop through it with:

```
dates.foreach { case (date, (id, rotation)) => 
   ...          
}
```

But in my code, this loop takes place within another loop and I would therefore like to advance myself in the dates keys, typically with a `currIndex : Int` variable that I would increment according to a condition.

I thought one could do something like:

```
date = dates.keys(currIndex)
```

but it doesn't look like this is possible... any idea how to do that?

Comment: Can you give an example also with the outer loop? The fact that you're even using loops at all would suggest that you're still thinking of the problem using an imperative paradigm (this is very common for anyone who's recently transitioned from Java).  It would be much easier to suggest an alternative if you could present the whole use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** trying to address your comment:

You can convert the whole keys to an `IndexedSeq` beforehand:

```
val keysSeq = dates.keySet.toIndexedSeq

// later, obtain an index
val index: Int = /* ... */
// lookup the key
val (valueInt, valueDouble) = dates(keysSeq(index))
```

---

*Previous answer*

You could try something like this:

```
dates.iterator.zipWithIndex.foreach {
  case ((key, (valueInt, valueDouble)), index) =>

}
```

Would that work for you? I'm not sure I properly understand your requirement of “increment[ing currIndex] according to a condition”…

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want. I need to be able to start from a given key and go on from there. With your solution, I would have to start over each time...